# Can I use a 60 watt Halogen bulb instead of a 100 watt incandescent bulb?

Tags: lighting

I have a new pendant fixture that calls for up to 100 watt bulb. Can I use a 60 watt Halogen bulb for a brighter effect?

Comment: Is 60W less than 100W?

Comment: A 60W halogen wouldn't be brighter than a 100W incandescent.  It would be slightly dimmer, as you need a 72W halogen to be equivalent to a 100W incandescent in light output.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Outlets are rated for current draw (wattage) not brightness. If you have a more efficient bulb, the outlet doesn't know or care.

Comment: This is true in this case, but not in general.  You are correct that outlets are rated for current draw, but current draw does not always equal wattage.  More efficient bulbs with a power factor less than 1, such as CFL and LED, can draw significantly more current than they turn into wattage.  The wattage listed on a lamp is assuming a power factor of 1 (such as for incandescent and halogen bulbs).